# How to capture Social Media feeds in Salesforce

Tags: webservices, facebook

We have a requirement of Capturing  the following to get converted to SFDC cases?

- Tweets having mentions to our Company Name
- Comments in FB page
- Linkedin Posts

Does anyone know any API which sends us such realtime data?

Can I use hubspot to achieve this?

Comment: Did any of the below posts answer your question? If so, please accept an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not worked on HubSpot, but that appears to have functionality to do what you are looking for with the Social Media integration.

I'm sure your Salesforce Account Manager will mention [Social Studio](http://www.salesforce.com/eu/marketing-cloud/features/social-media-marketing/) as to you as it is their native solution. I've worked with it a bit and it is a good tool but not a cheap option.

With Social Studio it is possible to listen on the channels like Twitter, Facebook and LinkedIn and have it creating Salesforce Social Accounts, Contacts and Cases from the Social Account feed.

You can customise the handling of social media posts by customising the Apex code template that Salesforce provide. I should be possible to do this with the integration with HubSpot too.

I should also mention the [Saleforce for Twitter and Facebook](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/apex/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HpEQEA0) AppExchange tool as this is free so a good starting point to trial things around social media.

There is also [LinkedIn Salesnavigator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004fovtEAA) on the AppExchange and Ebsta have a [LinkedIn integration tool](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3YcTEAV) but that is more about managing the contacts.

Answer (score 1):

1. In addition to the links that Dave provided, [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) provide
   Salesforce to Twitter/Facebook integration. For example:
   https://ifttt.com/connect/salesforce/twitter. This [blog post](http://cloud4good.com/announcements/recipes-success-salesforce-ifttt/) gives some more info on this particular type of integration.
2. [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) also provide integrations between Salesforce and other
   social media channels.
3. You may also benefit from [Social Accounts & Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=social_networks_overview.htm) standard
   feature in Salesforce. This used to also work with LinkedIn, but no
   longer does.
4. This [blog link](https://blog.internetcreations.com/2015/02/4-free-apps-integrate-social-media-salesforce/#.V157ueIrK70) also may be helpful, as it provides more detail
   and helpful screenshots about how to use some apps to see latest
   info about Accounts.
5. This [link](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2015/07/29/node-red-for-salesforce/) from Jeff Douglas, who used to be very senior at
   Appiro and is now one of the big brains behind [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en), is
   also really interesting as it shows step by step how to integrate
   Twitter and Salesforce using [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/). This is a really
   excellent tutorial, and showcases just how customizable it is (Jeff
   uses Node-RED to search for Twitter posts which contain key words,
   and then translates those posts into Spanish before creating them as
   lead records in Salesforce.
6. Finally, [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-integrate-Twitter-into-Salesforce) on the same topic provides some additional
   links that may be helpful.